# Documentation of self-created function

Tags: matlab

after having created an awesome :) function in Matlab, I want to add a documentation to this function, such that when the user enters

```
doc myfunction
```

he gets a documentation window of my instructions on how to use this function.

I am not completely sure, whether this feature is available to functions shared on the mathworks file exchange only. Should this be the case, how can I then add a help text such that the user gets my instruction on how to use the function when he enters

```
help myfunction
```

?

I tried [this.](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-help-for-your-program.html) 
However, my code (below) does not work. 
When I enter

```
help my_boxplot
```

the command window prints 3 empty lines...

```
function y = my_boxplot(x);
% MY_BOXPLOT Plot a boxplot of a datatable with 2 columns.  
%       The first column will be assigned to the x-axis, while the second
%       column will be assigned to the y axis. 
%       REMARK: The dots displayed in the respective boxes are the means of
%       the corresponding range (whiskers).
%       the MEDIAN
```

Thank you for your time so far.

Comment: That is the right way. The function must be in a file `my_boxplot.m` somewhere on the path, and be the first thing in that file. Whatever the first block of comments is in the file should be shown when typing `help my_boxplot`. — But you probably want to remove the semicolon at the end of the `function` line.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: The semicolon doesn't appear to be an issue. It looks syntactically correct. I'm guessing there may be multiple copies of `my_boxplot`. Type `which my_boxplot -all` into the Command Window to check for multiple .m files.

Comment: @gnovice tried that. it simply showed me my one file called my_boxplot.m. However, no change to the missing help output...

Comment: It should be either another my_boxplot like @gnovice indicated or you may be overriding `help` function itself. Otherwise your help text worked fine for me.

Comment: As other have pointed out, that should work. Just another thought: do you have a comment block anywhere above the snippet you show? Basically, the `help` function displays the first comment block. So if you have any sort of comment above that, that is what will get shown.